# Can't use numeric filter in a lazy loading datatable: ClassCastException String to Integer

Tags: java, hibernate, primefaces, lazy-loading, criteria

Here's my code:

xhtml:

```
            <p:dataTable id="dataTable" var="variable" value="#{myBean.lazyList}" 
                widgetVar="widgetVar"
                emptyMessage="Empty."
                filteredValue="#{myBean.filteredLazyList}"
                paginator="true" rows="100" 
                paginatorTemplate="{RowsPerPageDropdown} {FirstPageLink} {PreviousPageLink} {CurrentPageReport} {NextPageLink} {LastPageLink}"  
                rowsPerPageTemplate="100,150,200" lazy="true" rendered="true"
                selectionMode="single" selection="#{myBean.selectedRow}" > 

                <p:column id="yearColumn" filterBy="#{variable.year}" sortBy="#{variable.year}" headerText="Ano" filterMatchMode="contains" >
                    <h:outputText value="#{variable.year}" />
                </p:column>
```

Load method from my LazyDataModel implementation:

```
@Override
public List<Thing> load(int startingAt, int maxPerPage, String sortField, SortOrder sortOrder, Map<String, String> filters) {

    MyDAO dao = new MyDAO();

    try {
        myList = dao.findMyThings(startingAt, maxPerPage, sortField, sortOrder, filters);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    if(getRowCount() <= 0){
        setRowCount(dao.countMyThingsNoPagination(filters));
    }

    if(maxPerPage > 0){ 
        setPageSize(maxPerPage);
    }

    return myList;
}
```

Search method in my DAO class:

```
public List<Thing> findMyThings(int startingAt, int maxPerPage,
        String sortField, SortOrder sortOrder, Map<String, String> filters) {

    session = HibernateUtil.getSession();
    Criteria criteria =session.createCriteria(Thing.class); 

    if(maxPerPage > 0){
        criteria.setMaxResults(maxPerPage);
    }

    criteria.setFirstResult(startingAt);

    for(Map.Entry<String, String> entry : filters.entrySet()){
        if(!Util.isEmpty(entry.getValue())){
            if(entry.getKey().contains(".")){
                String first = (entry.getKey().split("\\."))[0];
                criteria.createAlias(first, first);
            }
            criteria.add(Restrictions.and(Restrictions.eq(entry.getKey(), entry.getValue())));
        }
    }

    if(sortField != null && !sortField.isEmpty()){

        if(sortOrder.equals(SortOrder.ASCENDING)){
            criteria.addOrder(Order.asc(sortField) );
        }
        else if(sortOrder.equals(SortOrder.DESCENDING)){
            criteria.addOrder(Order.desc(sortField) );
        }
    }
    else{
        criteria.addOrder(Order.desc("insertDate") );
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    List<Thing> things = (List<Thing>) criteria.list();

    session.close();
    return things;
}
```

Everything is working fine, except if I try to use the "year" column filter. If it was a String, it would work but, "year" is an int type, and I'm getting the following error:

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String cannot be cast to java.lang.Integer
    at org.hibernate.type.descriptor.java.IntegerTypeDescriptor.unwrap(IntegerTypeDescriptor.java:36)
    at org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql.IntegerTypeDescriptor$1.doBind(IntegerTypeDescriptor.java:57)
    at org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder.bind(BasicBinder.java:93)
    at org.hibernate.type.AbstractStandardBasicType.nullSafeSet(AbstractStandardBasicType.java:280)
    at org.hibernate.type.AbstractStandardBasicType.nullSafeSet(AbstractStandardBasicType.java:275)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.bindPositionalParameters(Loader.java:1968)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.bindParameterValues(Loader.java:1939)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.prepareQueryStatement(Loader.java:1874)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.executeQueryStatement(Loader.java:1835)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.executeQueryStatement(Loader.java:1815)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQuery(Loader.java:899)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQueryAndInitializeNonLazyCollections(Loader.java:341)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2522)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2508)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.listIgnoreQueryCache(Loader.java:2338)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.list(Loader.java:2333)
    at org.hibernate.loader.criteria.CriteriaLoader.list(CriteriaLoader.java:124)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.list(SessionImpl.java:1662)
    at org.hibernate.internal.CriteriaImpl.list(CriteriaImpl.java:374)
    at dao.ThingDAO.findThings(ThingDAO.java:99)
    at lazyDataModel.LazyThingDataModel.load(LazyThingDataModel.java:25)
    at org.primefaces.component.datatable.DataTable.loadLazyData(DataTable.java:737)
    at org.primefaces.component.datatable.feature.FilterFeature.encode(FilterFeature.java:85)
    at org.primefaces.component.datatable.DataTableRenderer.encodeEnd(DataTableRenderer.java:76)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeEnd(UIComponentBase.java:879)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1650)
    at com.sun.faces.context.PartialViewContextImpl$PhaseAwareVisitCallback.visit(PartialViewContextImpl.java:479)
    at com.sun.faces.component.visit.PartialVisitContext.invokeVisitCallback(PartialVisitContext.java:175)
    at org.primefaces.component.api.UIData.visitTree(UIData.java:675)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.visitTree(UIComponent.java:1487)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.visitTree(UIComponent.java:1487)
    at javax.faces.component.UIForm.visitTree(UIForm.java:331)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.visitTree(UIComponent.java:1487)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.visitTree(UIComponent.java:1487)
    at com.sun.faces.context.PartialViewContextImpl.processComponents(PartialViewContextImpl.java:361)
    at com.sun.faces.context.PartialViewContextImpl.processPartial(PartialViewContextImpl.java:282)
    at org.primefaces.context.PrimePartialViewContext.processPartial(PrimePartialViewContext.java:57)
    at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.encodeChildren(UIViewRoot.java:968)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1643)
    at com.sun.faces.application.view.FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.renderView(FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.java:378)
    at com.sun.faces.application.view.MultiViewHandler.renderView(MultiViewHandler.java:127)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.RenderResponsePhase.execute(RenderResponsePhase.java:117)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:97)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.render(LifecycleImpl.java:135)
    at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:309)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.primefaces.webapp.filter.FileUploadFilter.doFilter(FileUploadFilter.java:98)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:51)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:222)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:100)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:953)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:408)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1041)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:603)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:312)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1110)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:603)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
```

I thought in maybe using a converter to the filter but I have no idea how to set a converter to a p:column filter...

What should I do?

Thanks!!

Comment: Did you try this? http://code.google.com/p/primefaces/issues/detail?id=4030

Comment: Tried what, the converter in the `h:outputText` ? I tried it now, same result... :(

Comment: Looking at the stack trace, the issue appears to be with Hibernate.  at dao.ThingDAO.findThings(ThingDAO.java:99).  Which is line 99?

Comment: raylee, it is this line: `List<Thing> things = (List<Thing>) criteria.list();`

Answer (score 0):

Analysis of Exception Trace says that, following line causes the problem

```
List<Thing> things = (List<Thing>) criteria.list();
```

As you are getting `ClassCastException`, means results returned by `criteria.list()` is not able to cast properly to List. As you say, it works file with String but not with int, I can see the problem in Hibernate mapping file of `Thing` class.

When you change `year` datatye to `int`, you `need to change same in DB & Hibernate Mapping file` . Because of this missing, a DB result i.e Varchar type(String) is not able to cast to int. Hence the ClassCastException raised.

So, my suggestion is to change datatype in DB and Hibernate Mapping file as well. This should solve your problem.

Comment: Thank you for answering! I didn't change the year datatype. It is defined as integer in the database, and I'm using annotation instead of mapping file, and in my Entity class, the year variable is also declared as int. Any other suggestion? Thanks

Comment: OK. then i suppose you have a problem in a line Restrictions.ilike(...). Your code is checking for like operator but how can you apply it to Int data type. So, you need to change it to Restrictions.eq() .